# Custom Seek Bar

Tags: android

I want to make a custom seek bar.I have used this link as a reference 
    http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-custom-seekbar.html

but in output width of seek bar is coming too small

i dont know why the width is coming too small though my drawable images are not that small.This is my styled_progress.xml for android:progressDrawable of seek bar.

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/stats_screen_status_faded_progress_bar"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/stats_screen_status_active_progress_bar"/>
```

and this is the main xml file which contains seek bar.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="10"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:progress="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
            android:secondaryProgress="5"
            android:thumb="@drawable/stats_screen_status_arrow_pointer" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and i cant put images here as my reputation is very low.

Comment: did you subclassed SeekBar ?

Comment: then what does custom mean ?

Comment: did you use layer-list in styled_progress?

Comment: yeshhh.......@ArunCThomas

Comment: convert your `stats_screen_status_faded_progress_bar` and `stats_screen_status_active_progress_bar` to nine patches. The tutorial you followed is accurate but the guy is not using nine patches instead he is relying on the width of images which is not a good idea. Also change your Seekbar's android:layout_width="wrap_content" to "matchParent".

Comment: otherwise width and height of your images will vary depending on the density of screen.

Comment: shall i use this tutorial http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/...@M-WaJeEh

Comment: i have used fill parent still its coming too small...ya one more thing now m making the thumb transparent...@M-WaJeEh